# Components not showing up in JFrames

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Whenever I run this code the `JFrame` will show up, but none of my components will appear. I've done a few GUI projects before, but never had this problem before.

```
public class LibraryGUI {

    int x;
    Library library;
    ActionListener AL = null;
    BorderLayout mainLayout = new BorderLayout();
    GridLayout buttonLayout = new GridLayout(1, 4, 30, 30);
    GridLayout entryLayout = new GridLayout(2, 2, 1, 30);
    // below items will be in the main JFrame, where the library will be
    // displayed
    static JFrame mainLibrary;
    static JButton addButton = new JButton("Add an Item");
    static JButton checkInButton = new JButton("Check in an Item");
    static JButton checkOutButton = new JButton("Check out an Item");
    static JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save current library");
    static JList<Item> list;
    // below items will be in the "Add Item" JFrame
    static JFrame newItemFrame;
    static JButton addButton1 = new JButton("Add this Item");
    static JTextField titleJTF = new JTextField("Title of media");
    static JTextField formatJTF = new JTextField("Format of media");
    static JLabel titleJL = new JLabel("Title:");
    static JLabel formatJL = new JLabel("Format:");
    // below items will be in the "Check Out" JFrame
    static JFrame checkOutFrame;
    static JButton checkOutButton1 = new JButton("Check Out");
    static JTextField nameJTF = new JTextField("Name of Person");
    static JTextField dateJTF = new JTextField("Date of Check out");
    static JLabel nameJL = new JLabel("Name:");
    static JLabel dateJL = new JLabel("Date:");
    static JLabel titleJL1 = new JLabel("");
    // below items will be in the "Delete Confirmation" JFrame
    static JFrame deleteFrame;
    static JButton confirmButton = new JButton("Delete this Item");
    static JButton cancelDeleteButton = new JButton("Don't delete this Item");
    static JLabel confirmationJL = new JLabel();

    private void mainLibraryFrame() {

        mainLibrary = new JFrame("Lending Library");
        mainLibrary.setLayout(mainLayout);
        mainLibrary.setSize(500, 600);
        addButton.setActionCommand("open add");
        addButton.addActionListener(AL);
        checkInButton.setActionCommand("check in");
        checkInButton.addActionListener(AL);
        checkOutButton.setActionCommand("open check out");
        checkOutButton.addActionListener(AL);
        saveButton.setActionCommand("save");
        saveButton.addActionListener(AL);
        JPanel buttonHolder = new JPanel(buttonLayout);
        buttonHolder.add(addButton);
        buttonHolder.add(checkInButton);
        buttonHolder.add(checkOutButton);
        buttonHolder.add(saveButton);
        JPanel overViewHolder = new JPanel(mainLayout);
        mainLibrary.add(list, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainLibrary.add(buttonHolder, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainLibrary.setLocation(400, 200);
    }

    private void newItemFrame() {

        newItemFrame = new JFrame("Add Item");
        newItemFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        newItemFrame.setLocation(500, 300);
        addButton1.setActionCommand("add");
        addButton1.setSize(50, 30);
        addButton1.addActionListener(AL);
        JPanel newItemPanel = new JPanel(mainLayout);
        addButton1.setActionCommand("create");
        addButton1.setSize(50, 30);
        addButton1.addActionListener(AL);
        JPanel entryPanel = new JPanel(entryLayout);
        entryPanel.add(titleJL);
        entryPanel.add(titleJTF);
        entryPanel.add(formatJL);
        entryPanel.add(formatJTF);
        newItemPanel.add(entryPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        newItemPanel.add(addButton1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        newItemFrame.add(newItemPanel);
    }

    private void checkOutFrame() {

        checkOutFrame = new JFrame("Check Out");
        checkOutFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        checkOutFrame.setLocation(500, 300);
        JPanel checkOutEntryPanel = new JPanel(entryLayout);
        checkOutEntryPanel.add(nameJL);
        checkOutEntryPanel.add(nameJTF);
        checkOutEntryPanel.add(dateJL);
        checkOutEntryPanel.add(dateJTF);
        JPanel checkOutMainPanel = new JPanel(mainLayout);
        checkOutMainPanel.add(checkOutEntryPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        checkOutMainPanel.add(checkOutButton1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void deleteFrame() {

        JPanel deletePanel = new JPanel(mainLayout);
        deletePanel.add(confirmationJL, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        deletePanel.add(confirmButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public LibraryGUI(Library library) {

        this.library = library;
        list = new JList(this.library.container.toArray());
        mainLibraryFrame();
        newItemFrame();
        checkOutFrame();
        deleteFrame();
        mainLibrary.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I've been going over this code and cannot find anything that would `.setVisible(false)` and I've tried doing `.setVisible(true)` on everything but nothing seems to work.

Comment: its a `static` nightmare :)

Comment: yeah, for some reason I thought that might help... I'm really lost lol

Comment: You really shouldnt have all those frames. If anything, use the same one with different panels, setting visibility to true or false when needed. This code is also fairly hard to read, a and like @Reimeus said, everything is in static. When you say "The frame shows up, but no components appear", which frame are you referring to? EDIT: I also edited your tags - Replaced user-interface with gui - and even after approval, its not showing for me. I highly suggest editing it so the tags fit the questipn better, making this question more likely to get answered

Comment: Create each variable in the smallest scope possible. This code is very hard to read and hard to work with. If you need to be jumping between 3 places to read and create a simple initialization you are just asking to make silly mistakes. Why is `AL` null? Why do you create `overViewHolder`? Why do I have to know that there is a variable `mainLibrary` that is initialized when you call `mainLibraryFrame()`? However `deleteFrame` does nothing of the sorts. Either delegate the work (i.e. `void createAndShowMainLibraryFrame()`)  or return it: `JFrame mainLibraryFrame = buildMainLibraryFrame()`.

Comment: thanks for the responses, @VinceEmigh I should have said the frames, none of the components were showing up. The reason I have all the different frames is because the first 4 buttons on the mainLibraryFrame will set them to visible and allow you to add items to the list, delete an item from the list, or check an item out.

Comment: @Hammy One thing I must point out is that you never post any swing actions to the Event Dispatch Thread. Im not sure if this is the reasoning for your problems, but it will definitely cause problems when you start using listeners. Ima be honest, I didnt take a detailed look at your code (the lack of spacing makes my eyes bleed, please space it out if you want me to really check it out. its 10 times worse on a phone), but I really feel you should restructure ypur application, and possibly look intp Swing and the Event Dispatch Thread a little more

Comment: For everyone's sake, I used the code formatter of an IDE to make this code semi-readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing shows up because you do not specify a `CENTER` component for `BorderLayout` in your main frame. `BorderLayout` lays the side components relative to the center one, and if you don't specify the center component you won't see anything.

Having said that, many things of what you are doing don't look good (both visually and code-wise). Start by making a sketch (even in Paint) of what you want to get with sections clearly divided and labeled with the components they need to contain. Then work by that and bit by bit we can make it work better.

As for the mountain of fields you're creating: only declare a field if you are going to need to keep the reference for it for later uses. Most of your labels, for example, probably do not need to be fields, just local variables.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you don't need so many frames, but before I understand what you're even trying to achieve I can't say what you need to change.

Comment: Thank you so much, just tested it and it worked fine. Thank you for all of the other tips, they are much appreciated. I'm trying to improve myself all I can as a programmer so any other tips you have that I could improve, one other thing I noticed in the comments was the spacing. Where exactly should I space and do you have any examples of better-spaced coding?

Comment: @Hammy You can skim through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style for indentation examples. As for improving, go through the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) on topics you are not clear on. As for this specific doe, I suggest you edit it with the input you got from everyone here.